# Axon - How to get @QueryHandler handle method to return an Optional<MyType>

Tags: axon

**Note:**

The point of this question is not to just getting back a value that I ultimately want.
I can do that by simply not using `Optional`. 
I would like an elegant solution so I could start returning Optional.

**Explanation of what I tried to do:**

I used the `QueryGateway` with a signature that will query my handler. 
I broke out my code so you can see that on my `CompletableFuture` I will do a blocking get in order to retrieve the `Optional` that contains the object I really want. 
*Note* that I am not looking for a class that holds my optional. 
If this is not elegant then I may as well just do my null check.

The call to the query works, but I get the following error:

```
org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.query.AxonServerQueryDispatchException: CANCELLED: HTTP/2 error code: CANCEL
    Received Rst Stream  
    AXONIQ-5002
    58484@DESKTOP-CK6HLMM
```

Example of code that initiates the query:

```
UserProfileOptionByUserQuery q = new UserProfileOptionByUserQuery(userId);    
CompletableFuture<Optional<UserProfile>> query = 
  queryGateway.query(q,ResponseTypes.optionalInstanceOf(UserProfile.class));
Optional<UserProfile> optional = query.get();
```

Error occurs on the `query.get()` invocation.

Example of my Query Handler:

```
@QueryHandler
Optional<UserProfile> handle(UserProfileOptionByUserQuery query, @MetaDataValue(USER_INFO) UserInfo userInfo) {
    assertUserCanQuery(query, userInfo);
    return userProfileRepository.findById(query.getUserId());
}
```

The query handler works fine. 
Other efforts such as using `OptionalResponseType` would not initiate my query as desired.

Comment: If Optional is a bad choice.  Open to ideas on best practice for returning a single object with @QueryHandler given the object is not allowed to be null.  Plenty of ways to do this.  Looking for a Best Practice.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key lies with the exception you are receiving Stephen.

Just to verify for my own good, I've tested the following permutations when it comes to `Optional` query handling:

1. Query Handler returns `Optional`, Query Dispatcher uses `OptionalResponeType`
2. Query Handler returns `MyType`, Query Dispatcher uses `OptionalResponeType`
3. Query Handler returns `Optional`, Query Dispatcher uses `InstanceResponeType`

Added, I've tried out these permutations both with the `SimpleQueryBus` and Axon Server. Both buses on all three options worked completely fine for me.

This suggest to me that you should dive in to the `AxonServerQueryDispatchException` you are receiving.
Hence, I am going to give you a couple of follow up questions to further deduce what the problem is. I'd suggest to update you original question with the response(s) to them.

Do you have a more detailed stack trace per chance?
And, what versions of Axon Framework and Axon Server are you using?
Are you on the Standard Edition? Enterprise edition?
Does this behavior only happen for this exact `Optional` query handler you've shared with us?

Comment: Axon version = 4.2.1

Comment: This was not a show stopper for me, so I moved on.  I simply return the object, if there is no information I return null.   I can recreate the issue.  The stack trace provides very little information.  Complicated but I cannot get you a stack trace.  Only additional information:  message: "CANCELLED: Failed to read message."
location: "22220@DESKTOP-CK6HLMM"
details: "CANCELLED: Failed to read message."
details: "java.util.Optional"

Comment: Alright, happy to hear you have found another way around the problem. That's all that counts of course.